# accessing private members of a class in cuda kernel

Tags: c++, cuda, private-members

I created a class and passed its object to a cuda kernel.

The kernel's code is:

```
__global__ void kernel(pt *p,int n)
{
int id=blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
if(id<n)
{
    p[id]=p[id]*p[id];
}}
```

And it gives the following error: `error: ‘int pt::a’ is private`

The Question is: 
How can I access the private member of a class?

The program runs all right if there are no private members

```
class pt{
int a,b;
public:
pt(){}
pt(int x,int y)
{
    a=x;
    b=y;
}
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,pt p)
{
    out<<"("<<p.a<<","<<p.b<<")\n";
    return out;
}
int get_a()
{
    return this->a;
}
int get_b()
{
    return this->b;
}
__host__ __device__ pt operator*(pt p)
{
    pt temp;
    temp.a=a*p.a;
    temp.b=b*p.b;
    return temp;
}
pt operator[](pt p)
{
    pt temp;
    temp.a=p.a;
    temp.b=p.b;
    return temp;
}
void set_a(int p)
{
    a=p;
}
void set_b(int p)
{
    b=p;
}};
```

Comment: What is the definition of `pt`?

Comment: It appears that your function is declared friend outside of the class definition.  What is the definition of class pt?  Unless the friend function is declared inside the class definition, it is not a friend of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Private members of a class can only be accessed by its member functions and its friends.

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your C++ code.

This compiles on my machine (CUDA 4.0 Mac Osx)

```
#include <iostream>

class pt {
    int a,b;
public:
    __host__ __device__ pt(){}
    __host__ __device__ pt(int x,int y) : a(x), b(y)
    {
    }

int get_a()
{
    return this->a;
}
int get_b()
{
    return this->b;
}

__host__ __device__ pt operator*(pt p)
{
    pt temp;
    temp.a=a*p.a;
    temp.b=b*p.b;
    return temp;
}
pt operator[](pt p)
{
    pt temp;
    temp.a=p.a;
    temp.b=p.b;
    return temp;
}
void set_a(int p)
{
    a=p;
}
void set_b(int p)
{
    b=p;
}

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out,pt p);

};

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &out,pt p)
{
    out<<"("<<p.a<<","<<p.b<<")\n";
    return out;
}

__global__ void kernel(pt *p,int n)
{
int id=blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
if(id<n)
{
    p[id]=p[id]*p[id];
}}
```